# Subdominios con Cloudflare y XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

Intenté hacer un subdominio con XAMPP y Cloudflare para que cuando ingrese con en enlace *foro.dominio.net* me mande a *dominio.net/foro* y utilizar con XAMPP.

Creé un virtualhost pero no funciona, me sigue enviando a la página por defecto, como si fuese *dominio.net/*.

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
<VirtualHost foro.dominio.net:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/foro"
    ServerName foro.dominio.net
    ServerAlias www.foro.dominio.net
    <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/foro">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted  
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Esta es la configuración de mi subdominio en Cloudflare:

[image: Captura de la configuración de Cloudflare]

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Estás cometiendo un error muy común en las siguientes líneas:

```
<VirtualHost foro.dominio.net:80>
    ServerName foro.dominio.net
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

En la primera línea debes proporcionar una o varias combinaciones de direcciones IP (de la máquina) y puertos en las que vas a atender la página virtual `foro.dominio.net` ([ver documentación](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost)):

```
<VirtualHost addr[:port] [addr[:port]] ...>
    ServerName foro.dominio.net
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

El problema que sufres es debido a que **no coincide la resolución DNS del dominio `foro.dominio.net` con ninguna de las direcciones IP de tu máquina**.

Dicho registro DNS está resolviendo en los servidores de Cloudflare (por estar en modo **Proxied**).

Es posible que tampoco lo hiciera si tienes tu servidor tras un router NAT redirigiendo un puerto a un equipo interno. La resolución DNS de tu dominio resolvería a tu IP pública y, sin embargo, tu equipo interno tendría una dirección IP local.

Para solucionarlo debes indicar a Apache que atienda la página virtual indicada en `ServerName` en cualquier dirección IP de la máquina local usando el comodín `*`.

A continuación te muestro cómo hacerlo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foro.dominio.net
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Para que los cambios surtan efecto deberás reiniciar el servicio Apache desde el panel de control de XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentación de Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) comenta que en la etiqueta `VirtualHost` se pueden poner IPs de tu sistema, quizás el problema esté ahí.

De todas maneras, veo en tu web que redirige siempre a `https` (lo has configurado así en Cloudflare), por lo que deberías cambiar a algo así:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ...
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile     ruta del SSLCertificateFile que tienes de Cloudflare
   SSLCertificateKeyFile  ruta del SSLCertificateKeyFile que tienes de Cloudflare
</VirtualHost>
```

Reinicia Apache y debería funcionar.

Como apunte, si quieres aprovechar el potencial de la protección de Cloudflare solo deberías permitir que llegaran peticiones a tu servidor desde Cloudflare a tus puertos 80 y 443. Ahora mismo no es así.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda